# Redirecting Subdirectory to Subdomain with either htaccess or cpanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a subdirectory to a subdomain either using .htaccess or cpanel

redirects from

domain.in/subfolder

to

subfolder.domain.in

i m using cakephp app for both domain.in and subfolder.domain.in

each have separate core library

Please help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your `/subfolder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://subfolder.domain.in/$1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Or else:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain\.in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://subfolder.%1/$1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Comment: works great... but little correction           RewriteRule (.*) http://subfolder.domain.in%1/$1 [NE,R=302,L] - Thanks

Comment: for me not work RewriteRule (.*) http://subfolder.%1/$1 [NE,R=302,L].. please update on your main code script (not on comments).. thanks.. i will tick the mark after update ur code

Comment: Check official doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the following .htaccess file might work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.in$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://subfolder.domain.in/$1
```